# Is it possible to get the page title of a iframe object?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, wikipedia

I have an iFrame which refers to an Wikipedia page, I'd like to get the page title like when the Wiki Page is "Earth" then I'd like to return "Earth" with JQuery or smth else. Is that even possible?

EDIT

So what I have been told, that somehow with this code `function myFunction() { var result=document.getElementById("myFrame").src; var title = /[^/]*$/.exec(result)[0].replace(/_/g, " "); document.title=title }` I can get the page title. But it doesn't seem to work

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No...you can not access contents of cross domain iframes due to *"same origin policy"*

Comment: ok thank you, and there is no way you can achieve this?

Comment: Might be able to make ajax request to wikipedia api using params from the url used in iframe src but won't be able to track if user changes page inside iframe